# Python input in a self-repeating function

Tags: python, function, timer

I have a function with a:

```
threading.Timer(5.0, function_name).start ();
```

at the end.
What is the best way to do a

```
raw_input()
```

If I write it inside the function, the function obviously repeats it every 5 seconds, I want only a raw_input at the beginning and no more.

I only thought using a global variable, declared before the function.

With your method the input is repeated every time, in my case, the input should be prompted only once, at the first call of the function, no at the second, third, ... call by the timer

Comment: The best way would be to take input before starting the timer. What happens if the user takes more than 5 seconds to provide the input?

Comment: You know you can specify an argument to the `function_name`, right? http://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#threading.Timer

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this:

```
whatever = raw_input()
f = lambda: function_name(whatever)
threading.Timer(5.0, f).start()
```

As per Cthulhu's comment, `threading.Timer` allows to pass arguments, so you can use

```
threading.Timer(5.0, function_name, args=[raw_input()]).start()
```

instead. The other solution is more general, though.

Comment: Really no need, as `threading.Timer` allows to pass arguments. http://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#threading.Timer

Comment: Why the downvote? My Python is a bit rusty. Is it just because of what Cthulhu said or is my answer actually wrong for some reason?

Comment: Good point, since the answer seems valid enough. At least I was able to balance the score back to 0.